# Trouble with texshade package

Tags: floats, formatting

I have the issue that there are "@"s in front of my figure of a multiple sequence alignment. The figure itself looks fine. I just have no idea what I am missing in my document. Does anybody have experience using the texshade package? The issue does not happen when I put a minimal working code in a blank file, but when I want to incorporate said code in my thesis, I get those pesky @s. Are there any known compatibility issues?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

%packages in my thesis
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}  % for correct logo rendering
\usepackage{fancyhdr}  % for header/footer formatting
\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}
\usepackage{datetime}  % to update month in footer
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{biblatex} %Imports biblatex package
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\graphicspath{ {figures/} }
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
\usepackage[skip=5pt, margin=1cm]{caption}
\usepackage{mhchem}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array}  % more flexible tables
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{xspace}
\usepackage{abbreviations}

%packages for this figure
\usepackage{texshade} 
\usepackage{inconsolata}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{MSA.txt}
>gene1
ATGCTAGCATGACTCGTACGTA
>gene2
ATGCATGATGCATATCGATCTA
>gene3
ATGCGTAAGTAGTCTACATGTG
>gene4
ATGCTGACTGATGCTAGTAGCT
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}

\begin{texshade}{MSA.txt}

% IDENTITY HIGHLIGHTING
%\shadingmode[allmatchspecial]{identical}
\nomatchresidues{Gray70}{White}{upper}{bf}
\conservedresidues{Black}{LightCyan}{upper}{bf}
%\allmatchresidues{White}{Red}{upper}{bf}

% HIGHLIGHTING THRESHOLD
\threshold[100]{13} % [high]{low}

% SIDE NUMBERING
\shownumbering

% CONSENSUS
\hideconsensus

% TEXT SIZE
\namesfootnotesize 
\residuesfootnotesize 
%\legendfootnotesize
\numberingtiny

\end{texshade} 

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```